# Text inside icon - react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve something like this in react native.

[image]

In 'react-native-icon' we have direct implementation by using stacked icon as given by [this](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons#stacked-icons) link. Although the same thing is not working in react-native-vector-icon. And react-native-icon is no more supported. Any idea can this behavior be achieved by font-awesome or any suggestion for this kind a drawing in react-native. Or any ways to implement ***fa-stack-1x*** in react native.

PS: Please ignore the green patch in Image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make something like this?

```
<View>
<Icon/> // with position absolute
<Text>1</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Nopes, No help. Its messing up with my layout.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? It may need some refinement, though.

```
<View 
  style={{
    width: 100, 
    height: 100, 
    borderRadius: 50, 
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }}>
  <Text style={{color: '#ffffff'}}>1</Text>
</View>
```